# convert connect-statement from qt to pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots, pyqt5

how is the PyQt5 code of this Qt-connect-statement:

```
connect(frozenTableView->verticalScrollBar(), &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged,
          verticalScrollBar(), &QAbstractSlider::setValue)
```

Thank you!

Franz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
frozenTableView.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
    self.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!